# Why does the negation of a type predicate make an object be of type never?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a way of specifying whether a particular object's property – which is nullable – is null or not. I want to do this so I can filter out all the objects whose property is indeed null so that I can safely use the object and access its property.

In this example `Container` is the object and `nullableContent` is the property. I want to specify that the property is not null by using a conditional type in `Container`'s generic parameter. If `HasThing` is true then `nullableContent` is not null. If false then it is null.

This seems to work for the most part, even when creating a type predicate `hasContent`. In the case where `hasContent(container) === true` it can work out that `container` is of type `Container<true>`. However in the case where `hasContent(container) === false` TypeScript thinks that `container` is of type never, so I can no longer access any of its properties.

Why does this happen? Why can't TS work out that `container` is now simply of type `Container<false>`?

```js
interface Container<HasThing extends boolean = boolean> {
  id: string;
  nullableContent: HasThing extends true ? string : null;
}

const hasContent = (container: Container): container is Container<true> =>
  !!container.nullableContent;

function doThing(container: Container) {
  if (hasContent(container)) {
    return container;
  } else {
    // Below line gives error "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)"
    throw new Error(`Container with ID ${container.id} is empty`);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: I've created [this example on the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=22#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtx1NAPACTgGcAVAC1AHNkIAPSEAEyOQCN10AbCOEZAXjYduvAHzIA3gChkyYIwBcyImChUA3DOQgArp05xW3DOAjglhUhRDU6DZslU6UAfmWqqyJbv2aAvlJSCJgqyGTEJgxgAsgAFMFYOFBKkdgg0ACUSglgadByLKlJuE4Q4vyiWgCEVTl5UAB0PgZGEJFmYJpSMDogCGDAmMiM6ORU8Zi5SSmT9RmSWsAwceFE7eATielQGfPSsrJQEGA6UHx1SZqyfjScRCj7BwD0T8gAQhCc6ADuyJw4yEowAAbhAWNAoOgoMgAEQABUhAAdoGAAJ7IADk8gxw3QYO06GidGAoSGaORmPSoKgGIaYCIsQATABmZkATgyMK0sjAZEhv3SvwAolBIVBYgADIrbZDfYC85AASQAIsgACQSC7bBryG4kmgAW0RaIlGSuyACfiAA).

Answer (score 1):

Narrowing works best on unions. With a union on the `false` branch the compiler can just take out of the union the constituents that were handled on the `true` branch.

If there is no union to narrow, the compiler will intersect the original type with the guard type which will work out to  `Container<true>` on the `true` branch, but on the false branch it will try to do something like `Exclude<Container, Container<true>>` which results in `never` here (still trying to wrap my head around why ...)

The simplest solution is to transform the interface to a union:

```
type Container = {
  id: string;
} & ({ nullableContent: string } | { nullableContent: null })

const hasContent = (container: Container): container is  Exclude<Container, {  nullableContent: null }> =>
  !!container.nullableContent;

function doThing(container: Container) {
  if (hasContent(container)) {
    return container;
  } else {
    // Below line gives error "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)"
    throw new Error(`Container with ID ${container.id} is empty`);
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwJYIgJygXigbwCgopUATALigGdhN0BzAbkIF8oAyKACnygQCuAGyHIARkIjwkEJFVr0EDKOwA+BfsNESpiYLOBVBIlQEpChAMaJaUABbJq0-Ulw9rSNBkxVnXrKZUHijoWKTUJACiAB6WQgJkEAA8fqGYADQamiLiks4GRloqAHy4xcRQAISVwf6YAHTG2nl6BiyEAGYCCJbAqIhQZHAAKnaM3LVpvnp1pgQVqB08Dk6tSBMzaaZzRCQkmBDAApgIUJPeLCTsEELU0Lt7APSPUABCN3AA7lBCoVAMqAAbhAIlhMHBsAAiAAK4MgmFAUAA5OQkYM4CD+HBgFAINFULYBqBIMiMMDMEj6sBqNwAEwAZnpAE5TJCKiRgHZwd8MN9IphwZhuAADVLeKCfVCcqAASQAIlAACT4c5YerkdgE3EAWzAoGFpkuKjYQA)

Or if you want to keep the the type parameter:

```
type Container<HasThing extends boolean = boolean> = {
  id: string;
} & (HasThing extends true ? { nullableContent: string } : { nullableContent: null })

const hasContent = (container: Container): container is Container<true> =>
  !!container.nullableContent;

function doThing(container: Container) {
  if (hasContent(container)) {
    return container;
  } else {
    // Below line gives error "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)"
    throw new Error(`Container with ID ${container.id} is empty`);
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwJYIgJwDwAlkDOAKgBboDmUEAHsBAgCYFQBGccANhMglALyt2XHgD5+UAN4AoKFFQMAXFALBMFANxSAvlABkUABT5iZBJRp1GzVQFdoAfklQENjh2Qsu8JPWBKVamZQOkoSzq7unhDeln7hbsEAlFJSAMaIKlAkhDG+4gbpSGgYmEoxxViJSoUo6FhyzOV1OLYQYnwiMlAAhN01FZgAdC5uHl6IsZpSAGY2CKnAqIhQDHCkFAUTA2VbzYmSXajThtkEuUibRXv70rKymBDANpi8-c2asjoQHATQt3cAegBUAAQt84AB3KAcOpQcioABuEGYWEwcEwUAARAAFNGQTCgKAAcnkRJWcGRzjgwCo1FQmWWoEgxIwSMwRMGwAIBgATABmPkATkSmK6smAJDRUIwUIAopg0ZgDAADJolKAQ1ASqAASQAIlAACQSN4lQbyHT0qgAWzAoGViQ+wW0QA)

Comment: [PG](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQ2MCA7APAFQHxQLxSZQQAeKqAJgM5QCWqAZhAE5QDyUA-FAN5QDaAaTqooAawggA9g3YBdAFzshcqAF8oS1BABuLANwAoeimYMEAY2gBhKamAJ6LdAAkEVTAAt6Ac2Jk0aigAIykpOAgEUQJQ8MjUXB5DKDoKJSpgZl8jFNQAVzhEYIjbezRgJTcPb1Q-UnIgzLzobgys2s0ofMKjNUNQSEIARnwoAFESCzg8igh0UocnZgAaKAXHbWZ0JohsXAB6fa7dFlWAd08QTn7waEwAJlH1pf8GmmfN7eZm3G4RpQADFBDlAqBAIABbGjAKQhaDuKi0HyoBDFCAAOkxUAuV0MN0G8CQ5A+LFGhOQaHmdkWm2w+Og5OJ1I2LEw32gBEZlJJWx2ezxAzuQxGnMQFNQPNegRoXIlzKWbOaXCg-ygQOBRwBq1QUmAUARSJRaKgAAo2IIAJT04YAZie8s2Uso7wdzj5ytVQJBIMx6JCeT1eUYYvIEAoUAAkgBlU1DC3nS6cIA)

Comment: @ford04 the behavior of `Exclude` seems to have changed around 3.1 , you original sample does not work on that either .. not sure why .. maybe it's a bug .. maybe there is something else I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

Looks like TS is not able to narrow the type. Hell I don't know why, but I can propose the solution which in the minimum will change/impact your code. Change the type definition into the conditional union like:

```
type Container<T extends boolean = boolean> = T extends true ? {
  id: string;
  nullableContent: string;
} : {
  id: string;
  nullableContent: null;
}
```

Now rest of your code works with proper type narrowing and inference.